# How to write unittests for a custom pylint checker?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pylint

I have written a custom pylint checker [to check for non-i18n'ed strings in python code](https://github.com/rory/python-pylint-i18n). I'd like to write some unittests for that code now.

But how? I'd like to have tests with python code as a string, which will get passed through my plugin/checker and check the output?

I'd rather not write the strings out to temporary files and then invoke the pylint binary on it. Is there a cleaner more robust approach, which only tests my code?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at pylint's test directory. You will find several example there. For instance, unittest_checker_*.py files are all unit-tests for unique checker.

You may also be interested in functional tests: put some input file in `test/input` and expected message file in `test/messages`, then `python test_func.py` should run it. While this is more for pylint's core checker, it may be easily backported in your own project.